# Filtering Functionality results in "Array result was not expanded because it overwrites data in A5"

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I am trying to build a filter functionality within Spreadsheets itself.

The sheet looks as follows:
[image]

The function looks as follows:

```
=
IF(and(I4="ALL", I6="ALL", I8="ALL", I10="ALL"), query(Vastgoedbeheerders!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G ", 2),

IF(and(I4<>"ALL", I6="ALL", I8="ALL", I10="ALL"), query(Vastgoedbeheerders!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G where C="""&I4&""" ", 2),
IF(and(I4="ALL", I6<>"ALL", I8="ALL", I10="ALL"), query(Vastgoedbeheerders!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G where G="""&I6&""" ", 2),
IF(and(I4="ALL", I6="ALL", I8<>"ALL", I10="ALL"), query(Vastgoedbeheerders!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G where H="""&I8&""" ", 2),
IF(and(I4="ALL", I6="ALL", I8="ALL", I10<>"ALL"), query(Vastgoedbeheerders!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G where J="""&I10&""" ", 2),

IF(and(I4<>"ALL", I6<>"ALL", I8="ALL", I10="ALL"), query(Vastgoedbeheerders!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G where C="""&I4&""" and G="""&I6&""" ", 2),
IF(and(I4="ALL", I6<>"ALL", I8<>"ALL", I10="ALL"), query(Vastgoedbeheerders!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G where G="""&I6&""" and H="""&I8&""" ", 2),
IF(and(I4="ALL", I6="ALL", I8<>"ALL", I10<>"ALL"), query(Vastgoedbeheerders!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G where H="""&I8&""" and J="""&I10&""" ", 2),
IF(and(I4<>"ALL", I6="ALL", I8="ALL", I10<>"ALL"), query(Vastgoedbeheerders!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G where C="""&I4&""" and J="""&I10&""" ", 2),

IF(and(I4<>"ALL", I6="ALL", I8<>"ALL", I10="ALL"), query(Vastgoedbeheerders!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G where C="""&I4&""" and H="""&I8&""" ", 2),
IF(and(I4="ALL", I6<>"ALL", I8="ALL", I10<>"ALL"), query(Vastgoedbeheerders!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G where G="""&I6&""" and J="""&I10&""" ", 2),

IF(and(I4<>"ALL", I6<>"ALL", I8<>"ALL", I10="ALL"), query(Vastgoedbeheerders!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G where C="""&I4&""" and G="""&I6&""" and H="""&I8&""" ", 2),
IF(and(I4="ALL", I6<>"ALL", I8<>"ALL", I10<>"ALL"), query(Vastgoedbeheerders!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G where G="""&I6&""" and H="""&I8&""" and J="""&I10&""" ", 2),

IF(and(I4<>"ALL", I6="ALL", I8<>"ALL", I10<>"ALL"), query(Vastgoedbeheerders!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G where C="""&I4&""" and H="""&I8&""" and J="""&I10&""" ", 2),
IF(and(I4<>"ALL", I6<>"ALL", I8="ALL", I10<>"ALL"), query(Vastgoedbeheerders!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G where C="""&I4&""" and G="""&I6&""" and J="""&I10&""" ", 2),

IF(and(I4<>"ALL", I6<>"ALL", I8<>"ALL", I10<>"ALL"), query(Vastgoedbeheerders!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G where C="""&I4&""" and G="""&I6&""" and H="""&I8&""" and J="""&I10&""" ", 2)))))))))))))))))
```

For some reason it results into:

> Error Array result was not expanded because it overwrites data in A5.

I don't know what to change in the function in order for it to get it working correctly, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that your formula returns an array of values but it can't be shown because the required cells aren't empty.

One alternative is to use a function like [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en) or [ARRAY_CONSTRAIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036?hl=en) to limit the results.